# Connect to Azure Service Bus using RBAC stopped working

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I am using Managed Identity to connect to Azure Service Bus and it used to work fine.

This morning, I realized that this approach wasn't working anymore locally (using Visual Studio) and also on the deployed application (using managed identity).

I have a custom token provider class:

```
public class AzureServicebusManagedIdentityTokenProvider : TokenProvider
{
    private const string Resource = "https://servicebus.azure.net/";

    protected readonly string TenantId;

    public AzureServicebusManagedIdentityTokenProvider(string tenantId = null)
    {
        TenantId = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId) ? null : tenantId;
    }

    public override async Task<SecurityToken> GetTokenAsync(string appliesTo, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(Resource);
        return new JsonSecurityToken(accessToken, appliesTo);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string resource)
    {
        var authProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        return await authProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(resource, TenantId);
    }
}
```

Then for example to send a message:

```
var sbMessageSender = new MessageSender(new ServiceBusConnection("<my connectionstring>")
{
    TransportType = TransportType.Amqp,
    TokenProvider = new AzureServicebusManagedIdentityTokenProvider("<my tenant id>")
}, "my queue name", RetryPolicy.Default);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(<message to send>);
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
await sbMessageSender.SendAsync(message);
```

This error is thrown:

`Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidIssuer: Token issuer is invalid. TrackingId:5c6c17c7-7a9e-49f3-adf7-5dbfb35b3daf, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2019-10-29T08:56:17.`

I've checked that I have 'Azure Service Bus Data Owner' role and that the 'Azure App authentication' tool in visual studio is set to the appropriate account.

I am using these nuget packages:

- `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` v1.3.1
- `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` v3.4.0

Not sure If I am doing something stupid (as it used to work ) but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not working both locally _and_ on Azure? Are you specifying the `TenantID` on Azure, too or is that just for using your account locally? Have you tried catching the token and pasting it in a tool like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to see who the issuer is (since that's the error message)?

Comment: Is the managed identity of the application in the same tenant as where the token is from?

Comment: Yes the managed identity is in the same tenant (I can see it in the `Enterprise applications` blade of the AAd tenant). The account I am using from Vs is also in the same tenant and both have `Azure Service Bus Data Owner` role on the servicebus namespace.

Comment: Hmm... That's strange. If you're absolutely sure the configuration is correct (which you probably are since it used to work) I would expect best thing to do is to contact support. As far as I can see your code is exactly the same as the [example I have on GitHub](https://github.com/rickvdbosch/managed-identity-example). And I know that used to work :)

Comment: The only thing I'm not sure about is the `MessageSender`, since I'm 'just' using the `QueueClient`. Could you change your code to use that and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Just tried with `QueueClient` and still the same. I will contact support. anyway thanks a lot for your help. at least we double checked that I haven't missed obvious stuff.

Comment: I am currently dealing with the exact same problem, which started yesterday evening. I've got a ticket open but no response yet. I'll post an useful answers I get when I get them.

Comment: @AresonDeladious, the problem is gone but support team can't find any thing relevant for the moment on the cause of the issue. Let me know if you find something interesting

Comment: @Thomas Same here. I'm assuming there was an issue on their end at this point. I finally got a response to my ticket this morning, but nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to an issue within Azure. Per the response on my support ticket:

> ...this issue was caused by the latest service update where there was a syncing issue on the backend subscription ID info for the namespace. This only happens when a namespace is updated. Since RBAC authentication relies on constructing ARM resourceID using the stored subscription ID you saw authentication issues. The issue is now resolved and it should not re-occur.